# How to set dynamic height to view pager child fragments in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I am having view pager with 4 different fragments. In this, 3 fragments only contains webview. All the fragments load different contents. I unable to set a height based on the loaded content. For that, I wrote a custom viewpager to measure height of viewpager. For the first viewpager fragment, height is calculated properly. But when navigate to second or third fragment, viewpager height is not calculated accurately. I don't know, what is the issue is in my code and what i need to change to calculate proper height for each fragment after navigate to that view pager page. Here is my view pager and pager adapter codes. Kindly help me.

**Custom View pager:**

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

public CustomViewPager (Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPager (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    boolean wrapHeight = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;

    final View tab = getChildAt(0);
    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int tabHeight = tab.getMeasuredHeight();

    if (wrapHeight) {
        // Keep the current measured width.
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }

    int fragmentHeight = measureFragment(((Fragment) getAdapter().instantiateItem(this, getCurrentItem())).getView());
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(tabHeight + fragmentHeight + (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
public void setOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener listener) {
    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
    super.setOnPageChangeListener(listener);
}

@Override
public void addOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener listener) {
    super.addOnPageChangeListener(listener);

}

public int measureFragment(View view) {
    if (view == null)
        return 0;

    view.measure(0, 0);
    return view.getMeasuredHeight();
}
 }
```

**PagerAdapter:**

```
public class MerchantsCataAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
Context context;
Merchant merchant;
Fragment fragment;

private int mCurrentPosition = -1;

private String[] tabs = {"Home", "About Us","Promotions","Store Information"};

public MerchantsCataAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context,Merchant merchant) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    this.merchant = merchant;

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            fragment= new HomeContentFragment().newInstance(merchant.getCompany_home_content(),merchant.getVideo_url());
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment= new AboutusFragment().newInstance(merchant.getFull_description(),merchant.getVideo_url());
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment= new AboutusFragment().newInstance(merchant.getCompany_promotions(),merchant.getVideo_url());
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment= new FragmentStoreInformation().newInstance(merchant.getMerchantId(),merchant.getName());
            break;

    }
    return fragment;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabs.length;
}

public String getTabView(int position) {

    return tabs[position];
}
```

Comment: follow this [git hub dynamic view pager link](https://github.com/vabhishek/WrapContentViewPagerDemo/tree/master/DynamicViewPager-master) it may be help you

Comment: @NileshRathod, i tried this, But it is not helpful. It is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the answer. Place below property in Webview in xml. This will take webview height automatically based on the content.

```
android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
```